# apex interactive grid SELECT LIST

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

i use interactive grid in apex oracle , so i have to column linked together and two column it's a selected list , i try to use the value from first column to get any related value  in second column

exp :-

--CAR CATEGORY

```
  ID     name 
   1      BMW
   2      HONDA
```

--LIST OF CAR

```
   ID   CAR_CAT   NAME
    1     1        X5
    2     1        X6
    3     2        CIVIC
```

I NEED WHEN CHOOSE  THE BMW IN FIRST COLUMN , THE DATA APPEAR IS SECOND COLUMN (X5,X6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called *cascading LoV*.

```
select id   display_value,
       name return_value
from list_of_car
where car_cat = :CAR_CATEGORY_ID   --> this is a reference to interactive grid's column
                                   --  whose name is (I presume) car_category_id
```

Also, you need to set "Cascading LOV Parent Column(s)" property to `CAR_CATEGORY_ID`.